# SwiftUI UIRepresentable aspect ratio changes when device is rotated

Tags: swiftui, uikit

I have the following code

```
class UIViewTestClass: UIView {
    override func draw(_ rect: CGRect) {
        "Test".draw(at: CGPoint(x: rect.midX, y: rect.midY))
        let context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()
        context?.addRect(rect)
        context?.stroke(rect)
    }
}
struct TestUIView: UIViewRepresentable {
    typealias UIViewType = UIView
    func makeUIView(context: Context) -> UIView {
        let result = UIViewTestClass()
        result.backgroundColor = UIColor(.white)
        return result
    }
    
    func updateUIView(_ uiView: UIView, context: Context) {
    }
}

struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        TestUIView()
            .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, maxHeight: .infinity)
//            .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fit)
            .padding()
    }
}
```

It works fine when the view is presented but when the device is rotated the letters get stretched out or squeezed. Also, if I include the aspectRatio(contentMode: .fit) the text is correct but the view now only takes up a part of the frame.

How can I prevent this from happening?

Answer (score 1):

For a `UIView`, the `draw(_ rect: CGRect)` func is only called when UIKit decides it **needs** to be called.

If you put a `print("inside draw()")` statement in there, you'll see that it is *not* called when you rotate the device.

For UIKit implementation, we can implement `layoutSubviews()` add a call to `setNeedsDisplay()` to tell UIKit to call `draw()`.

I don't use SwiftUI ... but quick try looks like this will work:

```
class UIViewTestClass: UIView {
    override func draw(_ rect: CGRect) {
        "Test".draw(at: CGPoint(x: rect.midX, y: rect.midY))
        let context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()
        context?.addRect(rect)
        context?.stroke(rect)
    }
    override func layoutSubviews() {
        super.layoutSubviews()
        setNeedsDisplay()
    }
}
```